# advanced queries spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Can anyone explain me how to add advanced queries in crudrepository for example in my case I want to search users by their `firstname`.

Below is my `AppUsers` Class

```
public class AppUsers {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int id;
    @Column(name = "firstname")
    public String firstName;
    @Column(name = "lastname")
    public String lastName;

    public AppUsers() {
    }

    public AppUsers(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

This is the AppUsers Repository :

```
package com.developer.SpringMySQL.models;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;


public interface AppUsersRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<AppUsers,Integer> {

}
```

and this is the controller :

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    private AppUsersRepo usersRepository;

    @Autowired
    AppUsersRepo appRepo;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView doHome() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        mv.addObject("lists", appRepo.findAll());
        return mv;
    } 
}
```

Comment: try read the doc first https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 1):

It's naming convention on the repository method.
In your case you need to create a method in the Repository interface :

Set findByFirstName(String pFirstName);

See following links for more infos on the naming convention :

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Answer (score 0):

in Spring JPA you can do it like this:

```
Set<AppUsers> findByFirstName(String firstName);
```

Or in more complex you can use mysql like this (example from project of mine):

```
    @Query("SELECT NEW ps.exalt.timeoff.server.response.BasicInformation(e.id,e.name,e.email,e.profilePicture) FROM Employee e join e.roles r where r.id = 5 AND e.id > 0 AND activated= :enable")
Page<BasicInformation> findAllEmpWithApprovers(Pageable pageRequest,@Param("enable")boolean enable);
```

for more info check docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation